# How to set Media Box form elements default value?

Tags: hooks, uploads

I am developing a plugin to customize wordpress administration.

Creating / Editing an article, when i user insert an image from media library or uploading it, i want to clear the image title, as default is set as image file name, and i want to set Big as image size.

I am looking for the hook to work on it, i tried by using jquery but i guess the view button load the content in ajax.

```
add_action('admin_head-media-upload-popup','set_form_fields');

function set_form_fields() {
    echo"<script type=\"text/javascript\">
    jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
        alert('ciao');
        jQuery('tr.post-title td.field input').attr('value','');
    });
    </script>";
}
```

i am looking for how to set image post title='' and big radio button to "checked"

Comment: Show the code so we can integrate easier?

Comment: it's really long and it sets other changes. I'm looking on how to set form values in the media box. thanks for you help

Comment: @TrustWeb kaiser is not asking for your entire plugin code, but only the code related to your problem.

if you explore more, you will solve your problems, else ....

Comment: ok, i edited the post but i know it is not the right way to do it

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the title part, but you should be able to set some defaults for images using `update_option()`. You can try adding the following to your `functions.php` to set the default size to large - you should be able to take it back out after it's been called once so you're not updating the option every single time something loads:

```
update_option('image_default_size','large');
```

Comment: Or filter `option_image_default_size` and replace the size if it doesn't exist with `large`.